# SQL não retorna todos os registros da tabela

Tags: php, mysql, select

Minha aplicação consiste em uma página html na qual o usuário informa o código de um produto, a quantidade, e ele é mostrado abaixo. Eis que, se eu adiciono um produto, ele é inserido, porém, não retorna. E quando eu continuo a adicionar itens, só são listados os registros seguintes.

```
<?php
include_once("Classes\CONEXAO_BD.php");
session_start();

echo $ID_PEDIDO =  $_SESSION['novo_id'];

//Início da listagem
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'portfolio';

//Sql para listar os produtos adicionados
$comando_sql_listagem = "SELECT * FROM item_pedido INNER JOIN calcado ON item_pedido.ID_CALCADO = calcado.ID_CALCADO WHERE ID_PEDIDO = '".$ID_PEDIDO."' ";  


//Sql para calcular o preço dos produtos
$comando_sql_soma = "SELECT SUM(PRECO) FROM calcado INNER JOIN item_pedido ON calcado.ID_CALCADO = item_pedido.ID_CALCADO WHERE ID_PEDIDO = '".$ID_PEDIDO."' "; 

$link = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$banco);

$resultado_listagem = mysqli_query($link,$comando_sql_listagem) or die (mysqli_error($link)); 
$linha  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_listagem);

$resultado_soma = mysqli_query($link,$comando_sql_soma) or die (mysqli_error($link));
$total  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_soma);
?>
```

Listagem:

```
<?php
            if(!empty($linha))
            {   
                while($linha  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_listagem) ) 
                {   
            ?>  
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="ID"><?php echo $linha['ID_CALCADO']; ?></td>
                        <td data-title="NOME"><?php echo $linha['NOME']; ?></td>
                        <td data-title="NOME"><?php echo $linha['TAMANHO']; ?></td>
                        <td data-title="COR"><?php echo $linha['QUANTIDADE']; ?></td>
                        <td data-title="VALOR">R$ <?php echo $linha['PRECO']; ?></td>
                        <td data-title="">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#excluir" data-cpf="">
                            Excluir
                        </td>

                    </tr>
            <?php 
                }
            }
            else
            {
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <center>
                                <?php
                                echo "Nenhum produto adicionado";
                                ?>
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php   
            }   
            ?>
```

Código de inserção no banco de dados:

```
<?php
include_once("Classes/CONEXAO_BD.php");

$ID_CALCADO = $_GET["ID_CALCADO"];
$QUANTIDADE = $_GET["QUANTIDADE"];
$ID_PEDIDO  = $_GET["ID_PEDIDO"];
$TAMANHO  = $_GET["TAMANHO"];

$comando_sql = "insert into item_pedido (ID_CALCADO,QUANTIDADE,ID_PEDIDO,TAMANHO) values ('".$ID_CALCADO."' , '".$QUANTIDADE."' , '".$ID_PEDIDO."' , '".$TAMANHO."') ";
$nova_conexao = new CONEXAO_BD();
$nova_conexao->Abrir_conexao($comando_sql);
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.location.href="cadastro_pedido.php";
</script>
```

Comment: Wellingthon poderi dar mais detalhes?! Dá pra ver que aonde comenta:
//Sql para calcular o preço dos produtos
Acredito que se sua intenção for somar o total dos pedidos, também precisaria considerar as quantidades...Ex: SELECT SUM(calcado.PRECO * item_pedido.QUANTIDADE) FROM calcado INNER JOIN item_pedido ON...

Comment: Será que a consulta não está sendo feita antes da inclusão? Qual é o código que faz a inserção do produto?

Comment: Sim, mas se a consulta é vazia, uma mensagem aparece. Do contrário, a listagem(incompleta aparece na tela)

Comment: Desculpa se a pergunta for besta demais, mas o item que não aparece está nas duas tabelas, `item_pedido` e `calcado`? A query pode não estar retornando o registro por causa do `INNER JOIN`... Na mesma linha, pode mostrar também a query de `INSERT`?

Comment: Você precisa colocar o código todo, principalmente a parte do INSERT pra gente poder analisar, eu acredito que o INSERT está sendo feito depois da consulta, por isso o produto inserido não está na consulta

Comment: Sim, o item aparece nas duas tabelas. Na tabela 'calcados' os itens já foram previamente inseridos, entao eu uso o código acima para inserir os dados na outra tabela (item_pedido). Também desconfio que seja o INNER JOIN, mas não sei que outra query me retornaria todos os registros

Comment: Seu código deveria ser no primeiro select: item_pedido.id_calcado = calcado.id e no segundo select: calcado.id = item_pedido.id_calcado, peço que por favor coloque o create table calcado como código para analisarmos